# Change in foreign table affect the previous report

Tags: sql, database

Actually I am stuck in one issue. I have a table:

```
 tbl_color
+------------+
|id |  name  |
|---|--------|     
|1  |  Red   | 
|---|--------|
|2  |  Blue  |
|---|--------|     
|3  |  Black |      
+------------+

 tbl_clothes
+----------------+
|id  |   name    |
| 1  |   Pant    |
| 2  |   Shirt   |
| 3  |   T-shirt | 
+----------------+


tb_sales
+---------------------------------------+
|id | id_cloth |  id_color | sales_date | 
|---|----------|-----------|------------|
|1  |    1     |    1      | 2016/1/1   |
|---|----------|-----------|------------|
|2  |    1     |    3      | 2016/1/1   |
|---|----------|-----------|------------|
|3  |    1     |    1      | 2016/2/2   | 
+---------------------------------------+
```

So when I change one row of tbl_color to

```
tbl_color 
+---------------------------+
|id  | name   | modified_on |
|----|--------|-------------|
|1   | Orange | 2016/3/2    |
|----|--------|-------------|
|2   | Blue   | 2016/1/2    |
|----|--------|-------------|
|3   | Black  | 2016/1/2    |
+---------------------------+
```

So when I want to get report of sales on 2016/1/1

```
SELECT * from table tb_sales
JOIN  tbl_clothes ON  tbl_clothes.id = tbl_sales.id_cloth
JOIN  tbl_sales ON tbl_color.id = tbl_sales.id_color
where sales_date = '2016/1/1'
```

I get the report that have been modified no the original sales
How can I handle this issue?

Comment: You means you update color `Red` to `Orange` and then want to get the `Red` in query result? Does Any table in your database keep the original  **Red** record to select it?

Comment: no the Red gets replaced by Orange so how can I design db so that previous data doesn't get omitted?

Comment: Yes you should change tbl color so it would have historical value. Something like key colums of tbl color: id and apply_date and then 2 record (id,name,apply_date) = (1, red, 2016/1/1), (1, Orange, 2016/3/2) and the query will get max date in tbl_color that <= sales_date

Comment: but how can primary key be the same value?

Comment: If you follow that way, you must add columns to your primary keys, so it'll be **id** and **apply_date**